# Yii + renderPartial + window.location

Tags: jquery, redirect, yii, render

I have just created a View, that is loaded in ctonroller with "renderPartial" and then integrated into the main view. Unfortunately my JQuery onSuccess doesnt redirect the page:

```
$this -> widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType' => 'ajaxSubmit',
            'icon' => 'ok',
            'url' => Yii::app() -> createUrl('hr/userDeployment/createShipping'),
            'label' => 'Submit',
            'ajaxOptions' => array('success' => 'function(data){
                    Loading.show();
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if(obj.status=="success"){
                    $("#newUserDeployment").modal("hide");
                    window.location.replace(obj.url);
} else {
                    Loading.hide();
                    $("#userDeployment-form-error-div").show();
                    $("#userDeployment-form-error-div").html("");
                    var $inputs = $("#user-time-form :input");
                    $inputs.each(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("error");
                    $(this).closest(\'div[class^="control-group"]\').addClass("success validating");
});
                    for (var p in obj) {
                    if(document.getElementById(p)) {
                    $("#"+p).closest(\'div[class^="control-group"]\').removeClass("success");
                    $("#"+p).closest(\'div[class^="control-group"]\').addClass("error");
}
                    $("#userDeployment-form-error-div").append(obj[p]  + "<br/>");
}
}
}'),
    ));
```

This is the code of the button. On the main view the redirect in Success works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the fourth parameter of [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) is set to `true`. It's the `processOutput` variable, which turns Javascript on.

Comment: return $this -> renderPartial('_shippingDay', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,'date'=>$date),false,true); - it is set to true